# ASP.NET Core Web Application ExpireTimeSpan in UseCookieAuthentication doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I use Cookie Authentication with Google with following options:

```
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0)
        });

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
        {
            SignInScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            ClientId = "xxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxx"
        }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

After authorization via Google cookies will be expired after 30 minutes. And they are created for session.

[image]

What should I do to raise exparation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use your own cookies middleware when using ASP.NET Core Identity, as `app.UseIdentity()` already does it for you. You can configure the cookie lifetime/name/path directly in the Identity options, when calling `services.AddIdentity(options => { ...}`).

If you don't call `_signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync` with `isPersistent: true`, you get a session cookie, that expires when closing your browser. You can update your `ExternalLoginCallback` to fix that:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
        return View(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    // Specify isPersistent: true to avoid getting a session cookie.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        // Update any authentication tokens if login succeeded
        await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);

        _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return View("Lockout");
    }
    else
    {
        // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I put app.UseIdentity(); to Startup.cs, but now await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); is always null and it redirects me to login page when I authorized in app. I tried to search this issue, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: I resolve this issue to comment app.UseCookieAuthentication in Startup.cs
Now I have the exception in await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync  "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext".
I have services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(); and .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); in Startup and can't get rid of them because application doesn't work without them.

Comment: In the end, I removed app.UseIdentity(); from StartUp and added await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", User, properties); to ExternalLoginCallback like this:
[http://i.imgur.com/fpLiiGS.png](http://i.imgur.com/fpLiiGS.png)

It works for me.